# TYPO3 Wrap two columns?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

In the template setup I have set two columns up like this:

```
column1 < styles.content.get
column1.select.where = colPos = 1
column1.stdWrap {
  wrap = <div>|</div>
  required = 1
}
column2 < styles.content.get
column2.select.where = colPos = 2
column2.stdWrap {
  wrap = <div>|</div>
  required = 1
}
```

This wraps the column with a div but only if there is something in it.

Is there a way to put a wrap around BOTH columns if at least one of them has content?

At the moment I am achieving this using CSS `:empty {display:none;}` on the wrap in the template partial, but I would rather do it in Typoscript because `:empty` is not supported everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clean solution would be:
Either you define a COA in typoscript:

```
column_1_and_2 = COA
column_1_and_2.10 < .column1
column_1_and_2.20 < .column2
column_1_and_2.wrap = <div>|</div>
```

or you use a little bit of logic in your fluid:

```
<f:if condition="{column1}{column2}">
    <div>
        {column1->f:format.raw()}
        {column2->f:format.raw()}
    </div>
</f:if>
```

DON'T try to build logic with splitted wraps.

Comment: Great thanks. `COA` with `stdWrap.required = 1` works for me. I don't know why I didn't think of that!